# EBNF to JavaCC lexer

Tags: java, lexer, javacc

How do you convert  ::= [A-Za-z] into JavaCC?

What I have done:

```
TOKEN :
{
  < LETTER : (["A"-"Z"])>
}
```

but I don't know how to do the smaller letter parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
TOKEN :
{
  < LETTER : (["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"])>
}
```

[Reference](https://javacc.java.net/doc/javaccgrm.html):

> A character list describes a set of characters. A legal match for a character list is any character in this set. A character list is a list of character descriptors separated by commas within square brackets. Each character descriptor describes a single character or a range of characters (see character descriptor below), and this is added to the set of characters of the character list. If the character list is prefixed by the "~" symbol, the set of characters it represents is any UNICODE character not in the specified set.

Note that the rule:

```
TOKEN :
{
  < LETTER : (["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"])>
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
TOKEN :
{
  < LETTER : ["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"]>
}
```

which both match a single letter. If you want to repeat the class, you do need the parentheses and append a `+` quantifier:

```
TOKEN :
{
  < LETTERS : (["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"])+ >
}
```

Comment: the round brackets are used for repetition?

Comment: No, they are decoration.  Although if you do need repetition, you do need the parentheses.

Comment: what do you mean? so it becomes a repetition or no with the parentheses?

Comment: What I meant was that, if you want no repetition (or is that 1 repetition?), you can use either `["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"]` or `(["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"])`; it makes no difference. But if you want one or more letters you can use `(["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"])+` but can not use `["A"-"Z", "a"-"z"]+`.

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit containing @TheodoreNorvell's comments.